# Count the number of entries in a list in Netlogo

Tags: list, count, netlogo

I need to plot the number of teams in a network. Teams are defined as groups of agents in which all agents have links between each other.

Further, there is a global variable called "components", which is a list of the components. I want to plot the sum of entries of the list every tick.

I have tried with many similar versions of:

`plot ticks count components`

but it did not work: the graphic in netlogo showed me this error .

Thank you all!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, you have a list of agentsets called `components` and you wish to sum the sizes of each of those agentsets? You can use `map` and `sum` to do that (this is NetLogo 6 syntax):

```
plot sum map [ [comp] -> count comp ] components
```

[`map`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) takes a list, runs an anonymous reporter on each element of the list, and reports the results. So `map [ [comp] -> count comp ] components` is running `count` on each component in `components` and then reporting all of the counts in a list. `sum` then sums that list.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped me a lot! I did not want to sum every value of the list. I wanted to count how many entries the list "components" had. This is the code that achieved the feat:                                            `plot sum map [ [comp] -> comp / comp ] components`

Comment: Glad it helped, though apologies for misunderstanding. Note that `[ [comp] -> comp / comp ]` will always produce 1 (I didn't realize the components were numbers). Summing those ones just produces the length of that list. You can get the length much more simply by doing `length components`.